# PHP APC suddenly corrupts source files

Tags: php, apc

I have production app servers on AWS Ubuntu doing millions of hits daily.

The source files are synced from the main app server to S3 and then synced to secondary app servers when the servers start and upon changes.

This was working for a long time (many months) without issues.

In the last few days some time when a new app servers starts, the APC caching of the main source file got corrupted. The output of the server is showing a string of junk characters and then part of the PHP source code.

If I clear APC cache the code is re cached normally and everything works.

I'm using
APC Version 3.1.9
PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11

What can be causing this and how can I avoid it? I prefer not to upgrade APC/PHP at this time since I have confidence in this version from long time of flawless running.

Comment: Nobody answered but to help others with this situation.I added call to the main source file in a script that runs when the server starts before the massive traffic arrives. Hopefully it will pre warm the opcode cache and solve the issue